# Extreme Latency on Brand New CPU?

Tags: cpu, latency

I've recently picked up a Coolermaster HAF with an ASUS p8p67pro motherboard equipped with 8 gigs of ram while running on Windows 7.  This thing is hardly a month old, and yet it runs like an old dog with hip dysplasia.

I've downloaded the DPC Latency Checker V1.3.0 to help me find the root of the problem, yet to no avail.  I've disabled basically every driver that I've deemed unecessary, and it's not like I've got too many programs installed since this thing is about a month old.

At times, the Latency is in the red zone all the way across the screen, thus making it impossible to accomplish anything.  I'm a 3D artist, so I'm used to computer slow downs while working with large files, but the CPU slows down even while idle.

The problem is sporatic - sometimes really bad, sometimes super bad, to not so bad to no problem at all (though very rarely) -- making it harder to diagnose the problem.

Here's the hardware:

- Box: Coolermaster HAF 922
- Motherboard: ASUS P8P67 PRO
- CPU: LGA1155 socket for intel 2nd generation core / 3 processors
- Graphics: Nvidia Quadro 4000 + Nvidia gtx 560
- Network: ASUS PCE- N13 802.11b/g/n Wireless adapter
- Audio: Realtex ALC 892

The two Nvidia graphics cards are not SLI compatible (the Quadro being a Workstation card), but I have them hooked up to separate monitors and they seem to work fine.  Could that be part of the problem?

Needless to say, this is driving me mad.  Any help / advice would be awesome.

Comment: Are your temperatures okay?  Did you manually set your RAM latency?

Comment: There's a program which can actually show which drivers are biggest culprits for latency problems, but I can't remember its name. I think that it's part of the sysinternals package, so you can try checking there.

Comment: @AndrejaKo - Maybe not what you were thinking of, but try LatencyMon: http://www.resplendence.com/latencymon

Comment: @Shinrai Actually, it was exactly what I was thinking off. It's just that my memory isn't what it used to be.

Answer (score 1):

DPC latency is usually caused by a bad driver (or a bad device itself).  You say you've tried disabling some, but try disabling every single component that you can and see if it goes away, then reenable one a time until you find your culprit.  This could also be a virtual hardware driver installed by any apps.

In my experience, wireless adapters are NOTORIOUS for doing this, so I'd start there.

You might also use [LatencyMon](http://www.resplendence.com/latencymon) rather than DPC Latency Checker - it can be more specific as to what's making the calls.

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of things that I have encountered:

1. Insufficient power supply (more prevalent on notebooks; however, plausible on towers)
2. Disabling energy saving modes in the bios and "performance optimization" software

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the motherboard has a Bios that actually supports your CPU ?
If so, is your Windows 7 up to date with the latest Windows security-patches ? Some of the March, April and May 2018 patches for Meltdown and Spectre related issues may severely affect performance if the Bios doesn't have the matching micro-code updates for your CPU. If the Bios dates from before March 2018 and there isn't a newer one it may actually be better to uninstall those security updates.

And last, but certainly not least: The mismatched NVidia cards may be the source of your problem. In theory they should co-exist, but in practice...
In my experience you should avoid the NVidia supplied drivers and always install the Quadro FIRST, add the Geforce later. (In case of a pair of mismatched Quadro's or Geforces install the older card first.)

Best approach:

- uninstall ALL NVidia drivers, the Physx en GeForce experience software too.
- (If using Windows 10: Shutdown the computer with `shutdown /s` to make sure "Fast Start" is disabled.)
- Remove the GTX card.
- Let Windows re-discover the Quadro with its default drivers.
- (If using WIndows 10: Shutdown the computer with `shutdown /s` to make sure "Fast Start" is disabled.)
- Put he GTX card back.
- Let Windows figure out the driver.
- Do NOT install the NVida drivers, Physx and/or Geforce Experience. Keep it to the Microsoft WHQL certified drivers installed by Windows itself. That may cost you a couple of % in performance, but in my experience is far more stable than using the latest NVidia drivers.

And before I forget: If the Bios has an option to set which is the primary video-card you may want to experiment with that setting to see which card is best set as primary.
Swapping both cards in the PCIe clots may also help. Usually the Quadro is best placed in the 1st slot, which on most motherboards is the one closest to the CPU.